# How to create a NSMutableDictionary that won't crash when assigned nil?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutabledictionary

Is there a way to create a NSMutableDictionary category that won't crash when assigned a nil value? There is an objectForKeyedSubscript method that we can override for getting the value, but I am not finding the setter version.

I want my dictionary to not crash even when it's assigned nil through subscript.

e.g.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
dict[@"test"] = nil; //won't crash here
```

Comment: Maybe you could override setObject:forKey and objectForKey: replacing nil for [NSNull null] in those.

Comment: As Odrakir said, you can track the value that you are going to store in a Dictionary. And if it is empty as you may get from any service calls, replace it with null value.

Comment: Oh, by the way, if you are looking to do it with categories, you can't override methods, you'll have to do it with method swizzling... good luck with that :)

Comment: @Odrakir category is not needed. Cocoa already has 'setValue:forKey:'which does what Boon need.

Comment: Boon asked specifically for a category and setValue:forKey: doesn't add the value to the dictionary, but you are right, maybe that's what he wants.

Comment: I want dictionary to not crash even when it's assigned nil through literal syntax. How do you achieve that via overriding?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what your use case is but if you are just trying to assign an empty value to a key have you looked at NSNull?  If you assign a key in a dictionary to [NSNull null] it will give you most of the benefits of a nil value.

Comment: good one. I think the use case is straight forward, he is getting a nil value from service call, and after parsing trying to store it in a dictionary. This is a very frequent crash!!!

Comment: Well if the JSON is already deserialized and in a Foundation collection it can't have a "nil" value. ;)

Comment: I know NSNull - I am saying I want to create a category to prevent the dictionary from crashing when assigned a nil. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'setValue:forKey:' to set any value (including nil) in the dictionary

> **- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key**
>
> Adds a given key-value pair to the dictionary.
>    Note that when using key-value coding, the key
>   must be a string (see “Key-Value Coding Fundamentals”). Discussion
>   This method adds value and key to the dictionary using
>   setObject:forKey:, **unless value is nil in which case the method
>   instead attempts to remove key** using removeObjectForKey:.

Comment: I have no control who or how they set the value, I want to create a dictionary category that won't crash when they attempt to assign nil, even through dictionary literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do this in Objective-C. However, the code you posted does not crash.